# calling python interpreter with .py file as command line argument not working

Tags: python, command-line

I have set my path environment variable to include the python interpreter as well as my "python_scripts" folder. I can call the python interpreter or any .py files located in my "python_scripts" folder individually from anywhere on my machine as follows:

```
C:\> python.exe
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 
bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

or

```
C:\> test_code.py
```

and they both work fine. However, when I call the python interpreter followed by the script name:

```
C:\> python.exe test_code.py
```

it returns with the following error unless I'm located in my "python_scripts" folder:

```
python: can't open file 'test_code.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: is `test_code.py` in the current directory, or is it somewhere else?

Comment: `C:\> test_code.py` works fine? You're saying you can call `test_code.py`, which is located in `python_scripts`, directly from the `C:` drive? Are you ***sure***?

Comment: You should make sure that `python` is on your `PATH`. I've installed Anaconda many times and a variety of issues occur on that final step, be it administrator rights to modify PATH or otherwise. Then open a cmd window in the directory of the script you want to run.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `C:\> python.exe test_code.py` it will look in your current directory for `test_code.py`. If you pass an argument to `python.exe` it needs to be a valid absolute or relative path to a file that exists.

Answer (score 2):

That means that the file is on your Windows `%PATH%` variable. When you do `python.exe`, it looks in all sorts of places. For example, if your `PATH` looked like: `C:\;"C:\Program Files\Python 3\";C:\Users\user\python_scripts`, it would try `C:\python.exe`, then try `C:\Program Files\Python 3\python.exe` and find Python.

When you do `test_code.py`, it finds it as `C:\Users\user\python_scripts\test_code.py` (For example).

When you call `python.exe`, it just reads the filename and does not try to resolve the path.

Python uses a different path for importing, which can be seen as `sys.path`.

You can extend this using a `.pth` file in `python\Lib\site-packages`.

For example, if you add a `user_pth.pth` file with this content:

```
C:\Users\user\python_scripts\
```

Then you can do `import test_code` from any file.

So, you can invoke pythons importer by running your code as a module:

```
python.exe -m test_code
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give python.exe the full path to your script python.exe.
c:\test_code.py

Answer (score 0):

I copied my environment variable as
`C:\Python\Python38;C:\Users\ronegi\Desktop\PERSONAL\EDUREKA PYTHON`

**Now when I open Python.exe & after prompt I type as shown below**
`Hello_world.py`
It throws error below:
[image: error message]

I tried giving all tries.